# Plot variations in geometric sum within prescribed range

Tags: plotting, summation, computational-geometry

I have a simple geometric sum:

```
Sum[a^(j + 1), {j, 1, k}]
```

which evaluates to

```
(a^2*(-1 + a^k))/(-1 + a)
```

`a` has a given range of `-2/3<a<=1`. I want to plot the limit of this function as `k->Infinity` for the given range of `a`. (Where and if such limits exist.)

Is this possible? If so, how?

(`ListPlot` is fine, since `k` is an integer.)

Comment: Isn't it just `Plot[a^2/(1 - a), {a, -2/3, 1}]` as `a^k->0` for `k->Infinity` ?

Comment: Hm. I guess so. Silly me! OK, I'll try to work with that. Want to promote it to 'answered'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the values of your parameters, `-2/3<a<=1` and `k > 0 && k ∈ Integers`, the limit is rather simple as `a^k->0` for k->Infinity:

```
Plot[a^2/(1 - a), {a, -2/3, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is it really still true if $a=1$?

Comment: `Limit[(a^2*(-1 + a^k))/(-1 + a) /. {a -> 1}, {k -> Infinity}]` is `Indeterminate`

Comment: @Johu you have singularity at $a=1$ as divide by zero

Comment: This is what I thought. Yet you have $a\le 1$ in your answer, which is strictly speaking not correct.

Comment: @Johu the limit is correct - I mean the limit I described in my post. Smallness of $a^k$ is independent of singularity in the denominator.